# Flexbox Header Match Other Rows Content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm just beginning to figure out Flex box, is there any way to get the header row in a flex box to match the automatic width set by the next X-many rows? I need all the element in the row to be grouped together so I can't use columns.

Perhaps a column with rows inside?

Looking for something similar to a table-column element but for flexbox.

https://jsfiddle.net/benneb10/yjdabpzm/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: left;
}
.flexRowHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.flexBox {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}
.flexBox .flexRow:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #fff;
}
.flexRow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}
.multiLineFlexGroup {
  width: 50%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.multiLineFlexGroup .flexRow {
  align-items: center;
}
.flexItem {
  flex: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
}
button.icon {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexBox">
  <div class="flexRow flexRowHeader">
    <span class="flexItem">Heading A</span>
    <span class="flexItem">Heading B</span>
    <span class="flexItem">Heading C</span>
    <span class="flexItem">Heading D</span>
    <span class="flexItem">Heading E</span>
    <span class="flexItem">Heading F</span>
    <span class="flexItem">Heading G</span>
    <span class="flexItem">Heading H</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flexRow">
    <div class="flexItem">Test</div>
    <span class="flexItem">SMALL ITEM</span>
    <span class="flexItem">ANOTHER ITEM</span>
    <span class="flexItem">VERY VERY VERY LARGE ITEM</span>
    <div class="multiLineFlexGroup">
      <div class="flexRow">
        <span class="flexItem">ITEM</span>
        <span class="flexItem">ITEM</span>
        <span class="flexItem">ITEM</span>
        <span class="flexItem">ITEM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want each heading to start a column with width set by the widest content in the column?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want different flex-boxes to interact each other. The only way is to get header elements sizes and apply it to others via javascript(don't do this!).
Flex-boxes is not grid system or even tables. If you want tables, just use tables provided by css and html.